# Why does my while loop continue to call my menu function even after receiving different instruction

Tags: python

I have a simple Python program with multiple functions that displays a menu, takes an input, loops through and formats a CSV file then outputs information from that CSV file based on the user's input.

The Menu options look like

```
1: Call menu again
2: Create a default Report
3: More specified report
4: More specified Report
5: Exit program
```

I am using a while loop to loop over these menu options so I can call the menu repeatedly while the user continues to input a 1.

here is a look at the while loop

```
def main():
  banner()
  while True:
    choice = menu()
    #if the choice = 1, we call the menu function again 
    if choice == 1:
      menu()
    elif choice == 2:
      defaultReport()
      break
    elif choice == 3:
      #elif statement for a function not yet created in part 1
      pass
    elif choice == 4:
      #elif statement for a function not yet created in part 1
      pass
    elif choice ==5:
      print('\nExiting Program')
      break
```

The goal is to be able to call the menu function while the input (choice) = 1, then as soon as the input equals something else the program executes the code corresponding to the input without calling/displaying the menu again

Examp. of current problem:

1. 1 - calls/displays menu again     1st input
2. 1 - calls/displays menuagain  2nd input
3. 2 - should show a default report, but calls the menu/displays it once more    3rd input
4. 2- shows default output  4th input

Goal:

1. 1 - calls/displays menu again     1st input
2. 1 - calls/displays menu again      2nd input
3. 2- shows default output   3rd input

Menu function for those interested:

```
def menu():
  print('''\nMortality Rate Comparison Menu
    
1. Show This Menu Again
2. Full Mortality Report by State
3. Mortality for a Single State, by Date Range
4. Mortality Summary for all States
5. Exit \n ''')

  choice = input('Make your selection from the menu: ')
  while True:
    try:
      int(choice)
      break
    except:
      choice = input('Make your selection from the menu: ')
  while int(choice) > 5 or int(choice) < 1:
        choice = input('Make your selection from the menu: ')
  return int(choice)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, That was my mistake on the stack overflow side of things. I'm new here and am not used to posting/replying. The code is indented int he program (updated it in the question above to match that of the program)

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    ...
```

is an infinite loop that will run until it hits a break statement.

All your break statements are inside an if/elif branch, but not all the branches have a break. The logical reasons for not exiting the loop is then either (i) none of the if-tests match, or (ii) none of the branches with a break matches.

You can change your program to figure out what is going on, e.g. use asserts to verify that values are sensible and cover all exits to the loop so you know where it is going:

```
def main():
    banner()
    while True:
        choice = menu()
        assert isinstance(choice, int), "choice is not an int"
        assert 1 <= choice <= 5, "choice is not in [1..5]"

        if choice == 1:
          menu()
        #... etc
        elif choice == 5:
            print('\nExiting Program')
            break
        else:
            print("Nothing matched..?  Choice is:", choice)

        print("Debug...: end of while")
```

Comment: Alrighty, thank you. I should have shown the menu function as well. I check the value for the input within the function before returning it to make sure the value is an int and it is within the range of 1-5. I think what would have saved me here is some simple debugging like you had mentioned. Adding an else statement to see what the value of choice is while it is looping and then going from there tis the next step.

Answer (score -1):

This is likely because you are not resetting the value of choice. At the start of the loop you set it to menu() and then continued to do this each time, I'm not sure what menu() does but I'm guessing that it will be returning a 1 every time which is not what you would like.

Either make sure the value received from calling menu() changes by possibly giving it some parameter or ask for input each time, possibly through the python shell. Hope this helps